# Unable to create encrypted mp4 download using Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I've gone through the steps of uploading an asset, encoding it, and applying encryption settings.

For right now I am doing minimal testing and want to avoid the streaming fees, so progressive mp4 is fine- however it appears when I link to the mp4 via progressive download, the encryption is skipped and it is the original, unencrypted asset which gets downloaded.

Is there a way to download the mp4 with CENC or Fairplay or Clearkey applied?

Here's a screenshots of the configuration screen (redacted since I'm specifically asking about a misconfiguration on security, and not sure what details are important here):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot progressive download encrypted MP4 files. Mp4 files doesn't have binding for CENC or FairPlay. You need streaming protocols such as DASH, Smooth Streaming or HLS.

Cenk